# Best practices for events and date ranges

Tags: neo4j

I’m trying to find the best practice for how to store and then query a event like this.  User has purchased 3 items on separate dates.

Over that period there were two events that were held (events added in well after the user purchased the items as a retrospect, so at the time of purchase, event was not known).  I’m trying to see how many items were purchased during each event by that user.  How should I do that?

One solution but it sounds weird to me:  When inserting a event, scan and add a relationship to all vertices that match

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manage date-time types isn't exactly an easy task on Neo4j, even in 3.2 version.

You have two options:

- Hard way: convert all date to unix "timestamp" format ('s' or 'ms' from 1970), in order to calc date ranges.
- Easy, *convenient* way: use "**APOC**" ([here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures)), a set of procedures and functions available as plugin for Neo4j; installation can be a bit tricky but it's worth it, indeed. It has a good number of 'date-time' functions.